# How can I de-couple the two components of my python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, architecture, web-crawler

I'm trying to learn python development, and I have been reading on topics of architectural pattern and code design, as I want to stop hacking and really develop. I am implementing a webcrawler, and I know it has a problematic structure as you'll see, but I don't know how to fix it.

The crawlers will return a list of actions to input data in a mongoDB instance.

This is my general structure of my application:

> `Spiders`
>
> > `crawlers.py`
> > `connections.py`
> > `utils.py`
> > `__init__.py`

*crawlers.py* implements a class of type `Crawler`, and each specific crawler inherits it. Each Crawler has an attribute *table_name*, and a method: `crawl`.
In *connections.py*, I implemented a `pymongo` driver to connect to the DB. It expects a crawler as a parameter to it's `write` method. Now here come's the trick part... the crawler2 depends on the results of crawler1, so I end up with something like this:

```
from pymongo import InsertOne

class crawler1(Crawler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Crawler 1', 'table_A')

    def crawl(self):
        return list of InsertOne

class crawler2(Crawler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Crawler 2', 'table_B')

    def crawl(self, list_of_codes):
        return list of InsertOne # After crawling the list of codes/links
```

and then, in my connections, I create a class that expects a crawler.

```
class MongoDriver:
    def __init__.py
        self.db = MongoClient(...)

    def write(crawler, **kwargs):
        self.db[crawler.table_name].bulk_write(crawler.crawl(**kwargs))

    def get_list_of_codes():
        query = {}
        return [x['field'] for x in self.db.find(query)]
```

and so, here comes the (biggest) problem (because I think there are many other, some of which I can barely grasp, and others that I'm still totally blind to): the implementation of my connections needs context of the crawler!! For example:

```
mongo_driver = MongoDriver()
crawler1 = Crawler1()
crawler2 = Crawler2()
mongo_driver.write(crawler1)
mongo_driver.write(crawler2, list_of_codes=mongo_driver.get_list_of_codes())
```

How would one go about solving it? And what else is particularly worrysome in this construct? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I was thinking that maybe if I implemented a callback function in the crawlers... but would need to be before the actual crawling. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**: `MongoDriver` knows too much about your crawlers. You should separate the driver from `crawler1` and `crawler2`. I'm not sure what your `crawl` function returns, but I assume it is a list of objects of type `A`.

You could use an object such as `CrawlerService` to manage the dependency between `MongoDriver` and `Crawler`. This will separate the driver's write responsibility from the crawler's responsibility to crawl. The service will also manage the order of operations which in some cases may be considered good enough.

```py
class Repository:

    def write(for_table: str, objects: 'List[A]'):
        self.db[for_table].bulk_write(objects)

class CrawlerService:

    def __init__(self, repository: Repository, crawlers: List[Crawler]):
        ...
   
    def crawl(self):
        crawler1, crawler2 = crawlers
        result = [repository.write(x) for x in crawler1.crawl()]
        ... # work with crawler2 and result
```

**Problem 2**: `Crawler1` and `Crawler2` are pretty much the same; they only differ when we call the `crawl` function. Considering the principle DRY, you can separate the crawling algorithms into objects such as strategies and have one Crawler depend (with composition) on it.

```py
class CrawlStrategy(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def crawl(self) -> List[A]:
        pass
    
class CrawlStrategyA(CrawlStrategy):
    
    def crawl(self) -> List[A]:
        ...

class CrawlStrategyB(CrawlStrategy):
    
    def __init__(self, codes: List[int]):
        self.__codes = codes
    
    def crawl(self) -> List[A]:
        ...

    
class Crawler(ABC):
    
    def __init__(self, name: str, strategy: 'CrawlStrategy'):
        self.__name = name
        self.__strategy = strategy
       
    def crawl(self) -> List[int]:
        return self.__strategy.crawl()
```

By doing this the structure of `Crawler` (e.g. table name etc.) exists in only one place, and you can extend it later on.

**Problem 3**: From here, you have multiple approaches to improve the overall design. You can remove the `CrawlService` by creating new strategies which depend on your database connection. To express that one strategy depends on another (e.g. `crawler1` produces results for `crawler2`), you can compose two strategies together, such as:

```py
class StrategyA(Strategy):
   
     def __init__(self, other: Strategy, database: DB):
          self.__other = other
          self.__db = database
    
     def crawl(self) -> 'List[A]':
          result = self.__other.crawl()
          self.__db.write(result)
          xs = self.__db.find(...)
          # do something with xs
          ...
```

Of course, this is a simplified example, but will remove the need for a single mediator between your database connection and your crawlers, and will provide more flexibility. Also, the overall design is easier to test because all you have to do is unit test the strategy objects (and you can mock the database connection with ease to do DI).

From this point, the next steps for improving the overall design depend a lot on the implementation's complexity and on how much flexibility you need in general.

PS: You can also try other alternatives apart from Strategy Pattern, maybe depending on how many crawlers you have and their general structure you will have to use the Decorator pattern.

Comment: Perfect, a lot to grasp from your answer, I appreciate. I will work on those. Thanks!